# Count Based on Value of two columns in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a line graph that shows the number of hurricanes per category in different decades (1980, 1990, and 2000). I have the column for the hurricanes, HighCat, and the column for decade. However, I am need to get a count of the hurricane categories in HighCat per decade and put the count into storm_cnt column.

an example of the data:

```
HighCat Decade storm_cnt
CAT 1   1980   NA
CAT 2   1990   NA
CAT 1   1980   NA
CAT 3   1990   NA
CAT 2   2000   NA
CAT 5   1990   NA
CAT 4   2000   NA
CAT 5   1990   NA
TS      1990   NA
TS      2000   NA
TS      1990   NA
TS      2000   NA
```

The following is the script that I used

```
tracks_decade <- tracks %>% 
  group_by(HighCat, DECADE) %>% 
  summarize(storm_cnt = n()) 

ggplot(data = tracks) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = storm_cnt, y = HighCat, color = HighCat)) +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(DECADE), ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")
```

The output is a graph of decades that have no lines for the number of hurricanes per category per decade.

Comment: Perhaps start by using `data=tracks_decade` instead of `data=tracks` in your call to `ggplot()`.  There appear to be other issues in your data example and plotting code, however.  For example, there is no column `DECADE` in  `tracks` (rather, the column is called `Decade`).

Comment: yeah, I missed that. It still comes up with the same return though.

Comment: maybe start with something simple, like with `DECADE` on the x-axis, and `storm_cnt` on the y-axis, colored by `HighCat`, like this: `ggplot(tracks_decade, aes(DECADE, storm_cnt, color = HighCat)) + geom_line()`

Comment: the problem is I still have no values in storm_cnt. This where I am having issues.

Comment: `tracks_decade` does have data in `storm_cnt` when running the code you provide, **on the data that you provided** (given the inconsistency between `DECADE` and `Decade` is resolved. Perhaps the data you provide in the post is not truly reflective of your source data.  You may be better served by posting the result of `dput(head(tracks,50))` in the original post, rather than trying to hand construct an example of `tracks`

Comment: Gary any chance you could share the data (or the head of it if it's really long? dput is handy

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- structure(list(HighCat = c("CAT 1", "CAT 2", "CAT 1", "CAT 3", 
"CAT 2", "CAT 5", "CAT 4", "CAT 5"), Decade = c(1980L, 1990L, 
1980L, 1990L, 2000L, 1990L, 2000L, 1990L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
8L))

d |> count(HighCat, Decade, name = 'storm_cnt')
```

```
+   HighCat Decade storm_cnt
1   CAT 1   1980         2
2   CAT 2   1990         1
3   CAT 2   2000         1
4   CAT 3   1990         1
5   CAT 4   2000         1
6   CAT 5   1990         2
```

along these lines:

```
library(ggplot2)

d |> 
  count(HighCat, Decade, name = 'storm_cnt') |>
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(x = storm_cnt, y = HighCat, fill = HighCat)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Decade, ncol = 1, scales = "free_x", drop = FALSE)
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: the values show up in the variable storm_cnt, but they are not showing up in the line graph.